# Why use `yarn link`? Why not just symlink in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, symlink, yarnpkg

I have a local node module `foo` I'm working on, as a git submodule in my project. It's at `$TOP/submodules/foo`. I understand I can do:

```sh
(cd submodules/foo && yarn link)
yarn link foo
```

and that will create a chain of two symlinks from `node_modules/foo` to `submodules/foo` and now I can use it just like any other npm module in my main project, and it immediately reflects changes I make. Cool. But how is that any better than just:

```
ln -s ../submodules/foo node_modules/foo
```

? It doesn't seem that yarn records the symlink anywhere, so it won't sync to my other dev machines or anything.
Is there some good reason I should be using `yarn link`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe yarn internally does shimming for you, so that you can use it in multiple platforms where `ln -s` is simply not recognized.

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/src/cli/commands/link.js#L34
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/src/util/fs.js#L679

Also, it handles other subtle things for you and the syntax is simpler.

Comment: That makes some sense. But it still doesn't explain the weird double-symlinking.